# Undefined control sequence when passing 25 arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core, tikz-arrows, package-writing

Before I start to ask my question I would like to mention that I am well aware that the following may be non-standard or even frivolous LaTeX. I want to improve it and am open for suggestions.

Some time ago I wrote this package for drawing commutative diagrams. The reason was that I would like to use the syntax

```
\begin{diagram}
  \twobytwo[wide]
    {A}{X}
    {B}{Y}
  \arrow{nw}{ne}{a}[above]
  \arrow{sw}{se}{b}[below]
  \arrow{nw}{sw}{f}[left]
  \arrow{ne}{se}{g}[right]
\end{diagram}
```

which in my mind is more readable and pleasant than the one provided by [xymatrix](https://www.jmilne.org/not/Mxymatrix.pdf), [tikzcd](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) or [amscd](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amscd.pdf). The way it works is that I provide a diagram environment

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{\diagram}{}{
  \tikzpicture[diagram]
}{
  \endtikzpicture
}
```

an arrow command

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\arrow}{ommmo}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
      \draw[->] (#2) edge[decorate] node[font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
    }{
      \draw[->] (#2) edge[decorate] node[#5,font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
    }
  }{
    \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
      \draw[->,#1] (#2) edge[decorate,#1] node[font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
    }{
      \draw[->,#1] (#2) edge[decorate,#1] node[#5,font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
    }
  }
}
```

as well as grid commands like

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\twobytwo}{omomomomo}{
  \def\tempmatopt{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}
  \def\tempa{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}
  \def\tempaopt{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}
  \def\tempb{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}
  \def\tempbopt{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}
  \def\tempc{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}
  \def\tempcopt{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}
  \def\tempd{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}
  \def\tempdopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}
  \matrix[objects,\tempmatopt]{
    \node[\tempaopt] (nw) {\ensuremath{\tempa}};\&
    \node[\tempbopt] (ne) {\ensuremath{\tempb}};\\
    \node[\tempcopt] (sw) {\ensuremath{\tempc}};\&
    \node[\tempdopt] (se) {\ensuremath{\tempd}};\\
  };
}
```

As you can see even a 2x2 diagram needs **alot** of parameters, so I had to come up with a solution to pass more than the nine parameters `NewDocumentCommand` allows. The hack I used worked perfectly fine for diagrams of the size 2x3, 2x4, 3x4, 4x4, 5x4 but suddenly breaks for those of size 5x5. Explicitly when I try the command

```
\begin{diagram}
  \fivebyfive
    {A}{B}{C}{D}{E}
    {F}{G}{H}{I}{J}
    {K}{L}{M}{N}{O}
    {P}{Q}{R}{S}{T}
    {U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}
\end{diagram}
```

I get the error *Undefined control sequence. [{U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}]* even though the diagram nearly renders as expected. I don't understand why. The code for this command is the following monster:

```
% A B C D E
% F G H I J
% K L M N O
% P Q R S T
% U V W X Y
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\fivebyfive}{omomomomo}{
    \def\tempmatopt{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempa{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempaopt{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempb{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempbopt{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\tempc{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\tempcopt{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\tempd{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempdopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecont}{momomomom}{
    \def\tempe{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempeopt{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempf{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempfopt{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempg{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\tempgopt{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\temph{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\temphopt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempi{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcont}{omomomomo}{
    \def\tempiopt{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempj{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempjopt{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempk{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempkopt{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\templ{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\templopt{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\tempm{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempmopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcont}{momomomom}{
    \def\tempn{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempnopt{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempo{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempoopt{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempp{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\temppopt{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\tempq{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\tempqopt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempr{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcont}{omomomomo}{
    \def\tempropt{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\temps{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempsopt{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempt{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\temptopt{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\tempu{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\tempuopt{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\temvt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\temvtopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcontcont}{momomo}{
    \def\tempw{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempwopt{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempx{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempxopt{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempy{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\tempyopt{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \matrix[objects,\tempmatopt]{%
        \node[\tempaopt] (nnww) {\ensuremath{\tempa}};\&%
        \node[\tempbopt] (nnw) {\ensuremath{\tempb}};\&%
        \node[\tempcopt] (nn) {\ensuremath{\tempc}};\&%
        \node[\tempdopt] (nne) {\ensuremath{\tempd}};\&%
        \node[\tempeopt] (nnee) {\ensuremath{\tempe}};\\%
        \node[\tempfopt] (nww) {\ensuremath{\tempf}};\&%
        \node[\tempgopt] (nw) {\ensuremath{\tempg}};\&%
        \node[\temphopt] (n) {\ensuremath{\temph}};\&%
        \node[\tempiopt] (ne) {\ensuremath{\tempi}};\&%
        \node[\tempjopt] (nee) {\ensuremath{\tempj}};\\%
        \node[\tempkopt] (ww) {\ensuremath{\tempk}};\&%
        \node[\templopt] (w) {\ensuremath{\templ}};\&%
        \node[\tempmopt] (c) {\ensuremath{\tempm}};\&%
        \node[\tempnopt] (e) {\ensuremath{\tempn}};\&%
        \node[\tempoopt] (ee) {\ensuremath{\tempo}};\\%
        \node[\temppopt] (sww) {\ensuremath{\tempp}};\&%
        \node[\tempqopt] (sw) {\ensuremath{\tempq}};\&%
        \node[\tempropt] (s) {\ensuremath{\tempr}};\&%
        \node[\tempsopt] (se) {\ensuremath{\temps}};\&%
        \node[\temptopt] (see) {\ensuremath{\tempt}};\\%
        \node[\tempuopt] (ssww) {\ensuremath{\tempu}};\&%
        \node[\tempvopt] (ssw) {\ensuremath{\tempv}};\&%
        \node[\tempwopt] (ss) {\ensuremath{\tempw}};\&%
        \node[\tempxopt] (sse) {\ensuremath{\tempx}};\&%
        \node[\tempyopt] (ssee) {\ensuremath{\tempy}};\\%
    };
}
\makeatother
```

> What causes the error?

Thank you very much for your time!

PS: I know that one should not ask multiple questions at once. But given this much context I feel like it would be a shame not to mention two other problems I have. I do not expect any answers to them (the annoying bug is the question above) and beg your pardon.

**Bonus question**

- Using the `\tikzset` command I define attributes like `\tikzset{epi/.append style={->>}}` and things like `\arrow[epi,gray]{nw}{se}{}` work perfectly fine. But for the grid commands it doesn't. Writing `\twobytwo[wide,high]{}{}{}{}` throws the error *Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/wide,high'*. How do I fix this?
- If something is wrong with the name of the starting node, my arrows have an additional unintended arrow tip at their source (look like >-->). Why is this?

**Minimal (not) working example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse} % better command definition
\usepackage{xstring} % strings
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix} % node placement
    \usetikzlibrary{calc} % calculation
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} %snaked
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows} % right hook->
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % -Implies

% --- tikz styles and commands
\tikzset{diagram/.append style={
    baseline={($(current bounding box.center) + (0pt,-0.15\baselineskip)$)}
}}

\tikzset{objects/.append style={
    matrix of nodes,
    ampersand replacement=\&, % replaces the column indicator from & to \&
    text height=1.75ex, text depth=0.5ex, % fixes some text alignment issues with nodes
    column sep={5em,between origins}, row sep={4.5em,between origins} % width of node does not influence column spacing
}}

\tikzset{wide/.append style={
    column sep={6em,between origins}
}}
\tikzset{high/.append style={
    row sep={5.5em,between origins}
}}

\tikzset{equals/.append style={
    -,
    double,
    double distance=0.2em
}}
\tikzset{incl/.append style={right hook->}}
\tikzset{epi/.append style={->>}}
\tikzset{mono/.append style={>->}}
\tikzset{mapsto/.append style={|->}}
\tikzset{implies/.append style={
    arrows={-Implies},
    double,
    double distance=0.2em
}}

\tikzset{snaked/.append style={
    decoration={
        snake,
        amplitude=.4mm,
        segment length=2mm,
        pre length=1mm,
        post length=1mm
    }
}}
\tikzset{zigzaged/.append style={
    decoration={
        zigzag,
        amplitude=.4mm,
        segment length=2mm,
        pre length=1mm,
        post length=1mm
    }
}}
\tikzset{higher/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        yshift=+.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{lower/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        yshift=-.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{righter/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        xshift=+.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{lefter/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        xshift=-.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{ontop/.append style={
    fill=white
}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{diagram}{}{
    \tikzpicture[diagram]
}{
    \endtikzpicture
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arrow}{ommmo}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
            \draw[->] (#2) edge[decorate] node[font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }{
            \draw[->] (#2) edge[decorate] node[#5,font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }
    }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
            \draw[->,#1] (#2) edge[decorate,#1] node[font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }{
            \draw[->,#1] (#2) edge[decorate,#1] node[#5,font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }
    }
}

% --- common diagram shapes

% A B
% C D
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\twobytwo}{omomomomo}{
    \def\tempmatopt{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}
    \def\tempa{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}
    \def\tempaopt{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}
    \def\tempb{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}
    \def\tempbopt{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}
    \def\tempc{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}
    \def\tempcopt{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}
    \def\tempd{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}
    \def\tempdopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}
    \matrix[objects,\tempmatopt]{
        \node[\tempaopt] (nw) {\ensuremath{\tempa}};\&
        \node[\tempbopt] (ne) {\ensuremath{\tempb}};\\
        \node[\tempcopt] (sw) {\ensuremath{\tempc}};\&
        \node[\tempdopt] (se) {\ensuremath{\tempd}};\\
    };
}
\makeatother

% A B C D E
% F G H I J
% K L M N O
% P Q R S T
% U V W X Y
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\fivebyfive}{omomomomo}{
    \def\tempmatopt{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempa{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempaopt{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempb{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempbopt{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\tempc{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\tempcopt{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\tempd{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempdopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecont}{momomomom}{
    \def\tempe{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempeopt{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempf{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempfopt{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempg{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\tempgopt{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\temph{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\temphopt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempi{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcont}{omomomomo}{
    \def\tempiopt{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempj{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempjopt{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempk{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempkopt{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\templ{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\templopt{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\tempm{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempmopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcont}{momomomom}{
    \def\tempn{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempnopt{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempo{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempoopt{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempp{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\temppopt{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\tempq{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\tempqopt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempr{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcont}{omomomomo}{
    \def\tempropt{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\temps{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempsopt{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempt{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\temptopt{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\tempu{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \def\tempuopt{\IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{#7}}%
    \def\temvt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\temvtopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcontcont}{momomo}{
    \def\tempw{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1}}%
    \def\tempwopt{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2}}%
    \def\tempx{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{#3}}%
    \def\tempxopt{\IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{#4}}%
    \def\tempy{\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{#5}}%
    \def\tempyopt{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6}}%
    \matrix[objects,\tempmatopt]{%
        \node[\tempaopt] (nnww) {\ensuremath{\tempa}};\&%
        \node[\tempbopt] (nnw) {\ensuremath{\tempb}};\&%
        \node[\tempcopt] (nn) {\ensuremath{\tempc}};\&%
        \node[\tempdopt] (nne) {\ensuremath{\tempd}};\&%
        \node[\tempeopt] (nnee) {\ensuremath{\tempe}};\\%
        \node[\tempfopt] (nww) {\ensuremath{\tempf}};\&%
        \node[\tempgopt] (nw) {\ensuremath{\tempg}};\&%
        \node[\temphopt] (n) {\ensuremath{\temph}};\&%
        \node[\tempiopt] (ne) {\ensuremath{\tempi}};\&%
        \node[\tempjopt] (nee) {\ensuremath{\tempj}};\\%
        \node[\tempkopt] (ww) {\ensuremath{\tempk}};\&%
        \node[\templopt] (w) {\ensuremath{\templ}};\&%
        \node[\tempmopt] (c) {\ensuremath{\tempm}};\&%
        \node[\tempnopt] (e) {\ensuremath{\tempn}};\&%
        \node[\tempoopt] (ee) {\ensuremath{\tempo}};\\%
        \node[\temppopt] (sww) {\ensuremath{\tempp}};\&%
        \node[\tempqopt] (sw) {\ensuremath{\tempq}};\&%
        \node[\tempropt] (s) {\ensuremath{\tempr}};\&%
        \node[\tempsopt] (se) {\ensuremath{\temps}};\&%
        \node[\temptopt] (see) {\ensuremath{\tempt}};\\%
        \node[\tempuopt] (ssww) {\ensuremath{\tempu}};\&%
        \node[\tempvopt] (ssw) {\ensuremath{\tempv}};\&%
        \node[\tempwopt] (ss) {\ensuremath{\tempw}};\&%
        \node[\tempxopt] (sse) {\ensuremath{\tempx}};\&%
        \node[\tempyopt] (ssee) {\ensuremath{\tempy}};\\%
    };
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{diagram}
        \twobytwo[wide,high]
            {A}{B}
            {X}{Y}

        \arrow{nw}{ne}{a}[above]
        \arrow{sw}{se}{b}[below]
        \arrow{nw}{sw}{f}[left]
        \arrow{ne}{se}{g}[right]
    \end{diagram}

    \begin{diagram}
        \fivebyfive
            {A}{B}{C}{D}{E}
            {F}{G}{H}{I}{J}
            {K}{L}{M}{N}{O}
            {P}{Q}{R}{S}{T}
            {U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}
    \end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. This is a pretty complicated question, so it would be helpful if you could also include a complete compilable example document along with the code fragments so that people don't have to piece together all the code to try to help you.

Comment: please check your example is an example of the problem that you ask about. You say you get an undefined control sequence error but it gives `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/wide,high' `  which is a completely unrelated type of error related to the tikz and not related to your defintion forms at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spotted two issues.

Issue 1 was spotted by David Carlisle as well:

The definition of the macro `\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcont` contains

```
\def\temvt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
\def\temvtopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
```

instead of

```
\def\tempv{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
\def\tempvopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
```

Issue 2:

I think the error `pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/wide,high'.` is due to the circumstance that the macro `\tempmatopt` is placed into the optional argument of the command `\matrix` while not the macro `\tempmatopt` but the tokens forming its expansion should be placed there.

Probably something like this does the trick:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse} % better command definition
\usepackage{xstring} % strings
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix} % node placement
    \usetikzlibrary{calc} % calculation
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} %snaked
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows} % right hook->
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % -Implies

% --- tikz styles and commands
\tikzset{diagram/.append style={
    baseline={($(current bounding box.center) + (0pt,-0.15\baselineskip)$)}
}}

\tikzset{objects/.append style={
    matrix of nodes,
    ampersand replacement=\&, % replaces the column indicator from & to \&
    text height=1.75ex, text depth=0.5ex, % fixes some text alignment issues with nodes
    column sep={5em,between origins}, row sep={4.5em,between origins} % width of node does not influence column spacing
}}

\tikzset{wide/.append style={
    column sep={6em,between origins}
}}
\tikzset{high/.append style={
    row sep={5.5em,between origins}
}}

\tikzset{equals/.append style={
    -,
    double,
    double distance=0.2em
}}
\tikzset{incl/.append style={right hook->}}
\tikzset{epi/.append style={->>}}
\tikzset{mono/.append style={>->}}
\tikzset{mapsto/.append style={|->}}
\tikzset{implies/.append style={
    arrows={-Implies},
    double,
    double distance=0.2em
}}

\tikzset{snaked/.append style={
    decoration={
        snake,
        amplitude=.4mm,
        segment length=2mm,
        pre length=1mm,
        post length=1mm
    }
}}
\tikzset{zigzaged/.append style={
    decoration={
        zigzag,
        amplitude=.4mm,
        segment length=2mm,
        pre length=1mm,
        post length=1mm
    }
}}
\tikzset{higher/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        yshift=+.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{lower/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        yshift=-.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{righter/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        xshift=+.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{lefter/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        xshift=-.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{ontop/.append style={
    fill=white
}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{diagram}{}{
    \tikzpicture[diagram]
}{
    \endtikzpicture
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arrow}{ommmo}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
            \draw[->] (#2) edge[decorate] node[font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }{
            \draw[->] (#2) edge[decorate] node[#5,font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }
    }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
            \draw[->,#1] (#2) edge[decorate,#1] node[font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }{
            \draw[->,#1] (#2) edge[decorate,#1] node[#5,font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }
    }
}

% --- common diagram shapes

% A B
% C D
\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand\DefineIfValue[2]{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\def#1{}}{\def#1{#2}}%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\twobytwo}{omomomomo}{
    \DefineIfValue\tempmatopt{#1}
    \DefineIfValue\tempa{#2}
    \DefineIfValue\tempaopt{#3}
    \DefineIfValue\tempb{#4}
    \DefineIfValue\tempbopt{#5}
    \DefineIfValue\tempc{#6}
    \DefineIfValue\tempcopt{#7}
    \DefineIfValue\tempd{#8}
    \DefineIfValue\tempdopt{#9}
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\tempmatopt}{\matrix[objects,}]{
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempaopt] (nw) {\ensuremath{\tempa}};\&
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempbopt] (ne) {\ensuremath{\tempb}};\\
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempcopt] (sw) {\ensuremath{\tempc}};\&
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempdopt] (se) {\ensuremath{\tempd}};\\
    };
}
\makeatother

% A B C D E
% F G H I J
% K L M N O
% P Q R S T
% U V W X Y
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\fivebyfive}{omomomomo}{
    \DefineIfValue\tempmatopt{#1}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempa{#2}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempaopt{#3}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempb{#4}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempbopt{#5}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempc{#6}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempcopt{#7}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempd{#8}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempdopt{#9}%
    \@fivebyfivecont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecont}{momomomom}{
    \DefineIfValue\tempe{#1}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempeopt{#2}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempf{#3}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempfopt{#4}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempg{#5}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempgopt{#6}%
    \DefineIfValue\temph{#7}%
    \DefineIfValue\temphopt{#8}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempi{#9}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcont}{omomomomo}{
    \DefineIfValue\tempiopt{#1}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempj{#2}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempjopt{#3}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempk{#4}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempkopt{#5}%
    \DefineIfValue\templ{#6}%
    \DefineIfValue\templopt{#7}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempm{#8}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempmopt{#9}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcont}{momomomom}{
    \DefineIfValue\tempn{#1}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempnopt{#2}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempo{#3}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempoopt{#4}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempp{#5}%
    \DefineIfValue\temppopt{#6}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempq{#7}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempqopt{#8}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempr{#9}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcont}{omomomomo}{
    \DefineIfValue\tempropt{#1}%
    \DefineIfValue\temps{#2}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempsopt{#3}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempt{#4}%
    \DefineIfValue\temptopt{#5}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempu{#6}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempuopt{#7}%
%%
%    \def\temvt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
%    \def\temvtopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempv{#8}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempvopt{#9}%
    \@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcontcont%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@fivebyfivecontcontcontcontcontcont}{momomo}{
    \DefineIfValue\tempw{#1}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempwopt{#2}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempx{#3}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempxopt{#4}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempy{#5}%
    \DefineIfValue\tempyopt{#6}%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\tempmatopt}{\matrix[objects,}]{%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempaopt] (nnww) {\ensuremath{\tempa}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempbopt] (nnw) {\ensuremath{\tempb}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempcopt] (nn) {\ensuremath{\tempc}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempdopt] (nne) {\ensuremath{\tempd}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempeopt] (nnee) {\ensuremath{\tempe}};\\%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempfopt] (nww) {\ensuremath{\tempf}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempgopt] (nw) {\ensuremath{\tempg}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\temphopt] (n) {\ensuremath{\temph}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempiopt] (ne) {\ensuremath{\tempi}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempjopt] (nee) {\ensuremath{\tempj}};\\%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempkopt] (ww) {\ensuremath{\tempk}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\templopt] (w) {\ensuremath{\templ}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempmopt] (c) {\ensuremath{\tempm}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempnopt] (e) {\ensuremath{\tempn}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempoopt] (ee) {\ensuremath{\tempo}};\\%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\temppopt] (sww) {\ensuremath{\tempp}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempqopt] (sw) {\ensuremath{\tempq}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempropt] (s) {\ensuremath{\tempr}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempsopt] (se) {\ensuremath{\temps}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\temptopt] (see) {\ensuremath{\tempt}};\\%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempuopt] (ssww) {\ensuremath{\tempu}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempvopt] (ssw) {\ensuremath{\tempv}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempwopt] (ss) {\ensuremath{\tempw}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempxopt] (sse) {\ensuremath{\tempx}};\&%
        \expandafter\node\expandafter[\tempyopt] (ssee) {\ensuremath{\tempy}};\\%
    };
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{diagram}
        \twobytwo[wide,high]
            {A}{B}
            {X}{Y}

        \arrow{nw}{ne}{a}[above]
        \arrow{sw}{se}{b}[below]
        \arrow{nw}{sw}{f}[left]
        \arrow{ne}{se}{g}[right]
    \end{diagram}

    \begin{diagram}
        \fivebyfive
            {A}{B}{C}{D}{E}
            {F}{G}{H}{I}{J}
            {K}{L}{M}{N}{O}
            {P}{Q}{R}{S}{T}
            {U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}
    \end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

Probably you can define a loop for tail-recursively grabbing a non-optional and an optional argument until a list of argument-pairs of pattern {*⟨location⟩*}{*⟨matrix-command (either `\\` or `\&`)⟩*} is empty/blank:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse} % better command definition
\usepackage{xstring} % strings
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix} % node placement
    \usetikzlibrary{calc} % calculation
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} %snaked
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows} % right hook->
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % -Implies

% --- tikz styles and commands
\tikzset{diagram/.append style={
    baseline={($(current bounding box.center) + (0pt,-0.15\baselineskip)$)}
}}

\tikzset{objects/.append style={
    matrix of nodes,
    ampersand replacement=\&, % replaces the column indicator from & to \&
    text height=1.75ex, text depth=0.5ex, % fixes some text alignment issues with nodes
    column sep={5em,between origins}, row sep={4.5em,between origins} % width of node does not influence column spacing
}}

\tikzset{wide/.append style={
    column sep={6em,between origins}
}}
\tikzset{high/.append style={
    row sep={5.5em,between origins}
}}

\tikzset{equals/.append style={
    -,
    double,
    double distance=0.2em
}}
\tikzset{incl/.append style={right hook->}}
\tikzset{epi/.append style={->>}}
\tikzset{mono/.append style={>->}}
\tikzset{mapsto/.append style={|->}}
\tikzset{implies/.append style={
    arrows={-Implies},
    double,
    double distance=0.2em
}}

\tikzset{snaked/.append style={
    decoration={
        snake,
        amplitude=.4mm,
        segment length=2mm,
        pre length=1mm,
        post length=1mm
    }
}}
\tikzset{zigzaged/.append style={
    decoration={
        zigzag,
        amplitude=.4mm,
        segment length=2mm,
        pre length=1mm,
        post length=1mm
    }
}}
\tikzset{higher/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        yshift=+.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{lower/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        yshift=-.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{righter/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        xshift=+.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{lefter/.append style={
    transform canvas={
        xshift=-.3ex
    }
}}
\tikzset{ontop/.append style={
    fill=white
}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{diagram}{}{
    \tikzpicture[diagram]
}{
    \endtikzpicture
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arrow}{ommmo}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
            \draw[->] (#2) edge[decorate] node[font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }{
            \draw[->] (#2) edge[decorate] node[#5,font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }
    }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#5}{
            \draw[->,#1] (#2) edge[decorate,#1] node[font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }{
            \draw[->,#1] (#2) edge[decorate,#1] node[#5,font=\footnotesize] {\ensuremath{#4}} (#3);
        }
    }
}

% --- common diagram shapes

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\NodeLoop{%
  \long\def\NodeLoop#1#2#3\DELIMITER{%
    % #1 nodes collected so far
    % #2 \matrix-command when loop terminates
    % #3 remaining locations/table-commands
    \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\@firstoftwo#3{}{}}$%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi  
    {#2{#1};}%
    {\LoopNode{#1}{#2}#3\DELIMITER}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\LoopNode{%
  \long\def\LoopNode#1#2#3#4#5\DELIMITER{%
    % #1 nodes collected so far
    % #2 \matrix-command when loop terminates
    % #3 location of this node
    % #4 table-command (\& or \\) of this node
    % #5 remaining locations/table-commands
    \LoopNodeArgs{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  }%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand\LoopNodeArgs{mmmmmmo}{%
  % #1 nodes collected so far
  % #2 \matrix-command when loop terminates
  % #3 location of this node
  % #4 table-command (\& or \\) of this node
  % #5 remaining locations/table-commands
  % #6 label of this node
  % #7 opt argument of this node
  \IfNoValueTF{#7}{%
     \NodeLoop{#1\node(#3){\ensuremath{#6}};#4}%
  }{%
     \NodeLoop{#1\node[{#7}](#3){\ensuremath{#6}};#4}%
  }%
  {#2}#5\DELIMITER
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\twobytwo}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\NodeLoop{}{\matrix[objects]}}%
                  {\NodeLoop{}{\matrix[objects, #1]}}%
        {nw}{\&}
        {ne}{\\}
        {sw}{\&}
        {se}{\\}
        \DELIMITER 
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\fivebyfive}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\NodeLoop{}{\matrix[objects]}}%
                  {\NodeLoop{}{\matrix[objects, #1]}}%
        {nnww}{\&}
        {nnw}{\&}
        {nn}{\&}
        {nne}{\&}
        {nnee}{\\}
        {nww}{\&}
        {nw}{\&}
        {n}{\&}
        {ne}{\&}
        {nee}{\\}
        {ww}{\&}
        {w}{\&}
        {c}{\&}
        {e}{\&}
        {ee}{\\}
        {sww}{\&}
        {sw}{\&}
        {s}{\&}
        {se}{\&}
        {see}{\\}
        {ssww}{\&}
        {ssw}{\&}
        {ss}{\&}
        {sse}{\&}
        {ssee}{\\}
        \DELIMITER 
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{diagram}
        \twobytwo [column sep=2em, row sep=2em]
            {A}[green]{B}[brown]
            {C}[brown]{D}[green]

        \arrow{nw}{ne}{a}[above]
        \arrow{sw}{se}{b}[below]
        \arrow{nw}{sw}{f}[left]
        \arrow{ne}{se}{g}[right]
    \end{diagram}

    \noindent\hrule

     \begin{diagram}
        \fivebyfive [column sep=1em, row sep=1em]
            {A}[green]{B}[brown]{C}[green]{D}[brown]{E}[green]
            {F}[brown]{G}[green]{H}[brown]{I}[green]{J}[brown]
            {K}[green]{L}[brown]{M}[green]{N}[brown]{O}[green]
            {P}[brown]{Q}[green]{R}[brown]{S}[green]{T}[brown]
            {U}[green]{V}[brown]{W}[green]{X}[brown]{Y}[green]
    \end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this insightful answer and for showing me how to improve my code! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The first error is

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/wide,high
```

so I just used `\twobytwo[wide]`

theundefined commands were `\tempvopt` and `\tempv` which you do not define I assume due to typos and you intented

```
    \def\temvt{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\temvtopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
```

which you define but don't use to be

```
    \def\tempv{\IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{#8}}%
    \def\tempvopt{\IfNoValueTF{#9}{}{#9}}%
```

Comment: This is embarrassing. I checked the code many times but did not spot the additional $t$… Thanks for helping me!